# Is it possible in WPF to define multiple 'keyed'-Styles but with differing TargetTypes?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I am trying to get to grips with WPF Styles.

I was wondering if it is possible to define one `Style` key and then describe how it should be applied to different `TargetTypes`.

This approach is not working for me. I get an error message to say that `"TargetType 'TextBlock'" does not match the Element "Image".'`

It seems strange that every style:type combination needs it's own key name. I am doing something wrong? Is it completely the wrong approach?

e.g. in the Window.xaml:

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Bottom">
    <TabItem Content="{Binding UserContent}">
        <TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="users_24.gif"  Style="{StaticResource TabHdr}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Static r:Messages.Tab_Users}" Style="{StaticResource TabHdr}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem.Header>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

and in the Resources.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="TabHdr" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2, 1, 2, 1"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5, 1, 1, 1"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: `TargetType` is a "qualifier", whereas `x:Key` is an identifier. When a Style does not specify an identifier but does have a `TargetType` it applies to all controls that "qualify" for it. When identifier is specified, it's exclusive. They are just not things that work in parallel. They serve different purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that *if* you plan on explicitly setting the Style as you are (i.e. they are keyed styles - implicit styles are always found using the exact type of the class). You just have to set the **TargetType** to be the lowest base type that defines **all** the dependency properties you are setting. So in your case you are setting properties that are defined on FrameworkElement so you can just set the TargetType to **FrameworkElement**.

```
<Style x:Key="TabHdr" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
  <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2, 1, 2, 1"/>
</Style>
```

**Note:** If however you wanted to set something like Background (which is defined on Control) then you wouldn't be able to share that style with Image/TextBlock (which don't derive from Control) but you could create a style where the TargetType is Control in that case. You could even set the BasedOn of that style to the style you have for FrameworkElement so you can still share the other settings. E.g.

```
<Style x:Key="ctrl" TargetType="Control" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabHdr}">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

And then use it on multiple controls. E.g.

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource ctrl}" />
<Button Content="Foo" Style="{StaticResource ctrl}" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you are saying. However, the styles are not common. e.g. the margin on the Image maybe/is different to the margin on the TextBlock. Looks like I'll have to use differing keys...

Comment: Well if the properties you want to set are different then you have no choice but to create different styles. If the properties you wanted to set were the same but the values were different then you could either use different styles or set the value to a binding that provides the style but in the case of types then I would say it would be cleaner to use different styles.

Answer (score 0):

To short answer your question.. you can't!

You are assigning TabHdr style to a TextBlock, but the style is defined as a Image control style. You can't do that.
If all of your control have to have a specific style, you can define a style without a key but with a specific TargetType. For example, in the code you provided, the TextBlock is applied to all TextBlocks.

PS: If you have to create a kind of theme for your application you can inherit and extend a base style using the BasedOn attribute.